# Create report from dynamically built dataset

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, report, data-analysis

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to generate reports (either via xlsx or MS report viewer). The biggest issue is my dataset being dynamically created. Here's what I have:

One or more terminals periodically fill a cloud-hosted database with information about where the info is coming from, the global key and the value corresponding to the pair (origin, key).

So I end up with a table like:

```
TERMINAL_NO|GLOBAL_KEY|DECIMAL_VALUE
===========|==========|=============
123        |9876      |1.00
123        |9875      |0.50
123        |9872      |-4.00
234        |9876      |3.00
234        |9875      |5.45
234        |9872      |2.50
```

And I have made an app that transforms that into a DataSet with one column per TERMINAL_NO, and each row is every distinct GLOBAL_KEY, storing the corresponding DECIMAL_VALUES for each pair. However, that's the issue - I can't find a way to generate reports or xlsx files with dynamically created DataSets, as I understood both of them need typed DataSets to work with.

Is there an easier way to gather that data, or am I doing this wrong?

**08-15-20 EDIT**
As per @jdweng, I did try the method depicted there, but I can't make the reportViewer display the actual data. Currently I have the following:

```cs
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSetStock", LoadData());
//LoadData() returns a filled datatable.
            RView.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            RView.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            RView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            RView.LocalReport.ReportPath = "StockReport.rdlc";
            RView.RefreshReport();
```

Yet, all I get is an empty reportviewer inside the winformshost control.

Comment: Look at example after 6 witch makes the datasource a dataset : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/using-the-winforms-reportviewer-control?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: you can also try https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/888174/Dynamically-Creating-an-RDLC-Report-Just-Using-a-D

Comment: @jdweng I tried your suggestion but I've found another bug now...

Comment: @nbk I'd rather not use 3rd party code if I can help it, so I'll leave your suggestion for last resort, but thanks very much for the hint.

Comment: As long the copyleft is ok, i use code,why should you reinvent the wheel a new

Comment: The rdlc is http format and is text.  So you can open the rdlc with notepad.  There is a command text which is the database query.  There may be something wrong with the query.

Comment: @jdweng I think I'm following the reference correctly - I instantiate a new ReportDataSource `new ReportDataSource("DataSourceStock", GetData();`, where GetData returns me a filled DataTable (I checked it was filled during a breakpoint), clear my reportView.DataSources, add the reportDataSource I've created and set the ReportPath to a local *.rdlc file, ending with a RefreshReport() method. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @nbk That code worked with some adjustments, yeah. I believe the other options ain't working because my rdlc file is empty, so the reportViewer doesn't know how to display the data on the reportViewer.

Comment: @nbk I think I'll be using your solution. Do I answer my own question or do you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: post a helpful answer with enough details and description, so that others can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @nbk's suggestion, I went with a report generator code made by Nadir (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/888174/Dynamically-Creating-an-RDLC-Report-Just-Using-a-D), by using the provided .cs files.

Just had to make a few changes on the xaml because I'm not using a logo image. I already had my dataset (just had to change the column names to be cls-compliant) and it worked flawlessly. I didn't have to use the userControl folder, as I'm working on WPF and already had a winforms host control with a reportviewer control on it.